# Include a plain javascript file in dojo build profile

Tags: javascript, build, dojo, amd

I'm building dojo 1.8.3 with a profile that puts all of dojo and my own AMD code into a single layer. I'd also like to include some non-AMD libraries (e.g. history.js) and polyfills in the same file, as-is. Is it possible to do this with the dojo build system?

The current build profile:

```
var profile = (function () {
var conf = {
    basePath: ".",
    layerOptimize: "closure",
    optimize: "closure",
    cssOptimize: "comments",
    mini: true,
    selectorEngine: "acme",

    defaultConfig: {
        hasCache: {
            "dojo-built": 1,
            "dojo-loader": 1,
            "dom": 1,
            "host-browser": 1,
            "config-selectorEngine": "acme"
        },
        async: 1
    },

    packages: [{
        name: "dojo",
        location: "./dojo"
    }, {
        name: "dijit",
        location: "./dijit"
    }, {
        name: "dojox",
        location: "./dojox"
    }, {
        name: "MyApp",
        location: "./MyApp"
    }, {
        name: "bootstrap",
        location: "./bootstrap"
    }],

    layers: {
        "dojo": {
            name: "dojo",
            include: [
                "dojo/dojo",
                "dojo/domReady",
                "MyApp/common",
                "MyApp/bootstrap"
            ]
        }
    }
}
return conf;
}());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the files as a package, dojo will automatically wrap them and include them. I added this to the packages section:

```
{
    name: "libs",
    location: "./libs"
}
```

and changed the layer definiton to:

```
"dojo": {
     name: "dojo",
     include: [
         "dojo/dojo",
         "dojo/domReady",
         "libs/history/native.history",
         "libs/base64/base64",
         "MyApp/common",
         "MyApp/bootstrap"
     ]
 }
```

(base64 and native.history are the plain Javascript libraries)

Comment: When using this style to include plain javascript, do you still need to do a require. e.g. require("libs/history/native.history", function() { .. do something..});
I ask because I am attempting to migrate our code to the 1.9 builder (from 1.6) and we have some plain javascript that is included in a layer. Once the layer is loaded the functions are available in the global namespace (without a require) and I'd like to avoid finding all the usages and changing those

Comment: You'll need to require it somewhere to make sure that it gets included in the built JS (or to be pulled in by AMD). Having required it once, it should be available from then on in whatever namespace your plain code defines (e.g. window.history for history.js). You won't need to require it in every context you use it.

Comment: @synecdoche not working when I tried to include handlebars.